# Mods folder missing from .minecraft folder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have Windows 10 and when I go to look in my .minecraft folder in the AppData folder, the mods folder is not there.

[image]

How can I find the mods folder?

Comment: Can't you create the folder?

Comment: poor soul thinks modding is built in with minecraft.

we wish... we wish

Comment: Your average Minecrfat community

Answer (score 7):

Vanilla Minecraft does not have a "mods" folder. Most likely case is that you need to install Forge Mod Loader, [which you can download here](http://files.minecraftforge.net/).

If you do already have Forge and the folder is still missing, it may have been deleted by mistake. You should be able to create a new folder in the .minecraft directory, and call it "mods".

Answer (score 1):

If you got Forge and can't find the mods folder, you have to run the game at least once, then create a new profile on the launcher and for the game version select the one with Forge in the name.

Answer (score 0):

When you choose your modded provider in my case forge for your profile and hit play as it loads it creates your folder for you and in .minecraft you will now find a mods folder.

It is quite confusing if you are new to mods. There is very little info out there on how it appears I have seen many people create a folder named mods and throw stuff in there not knowing what went wrong.

We have all been there. Hope this helped

Answer (score -1):

You need to create the folder on your own. 
Just create a new folder named "mods" and put your mods in there and that should do it.